# TypeScript error: Cannot find module 'React'

Tags: typescript, tsc

I've been trying to compile my project for several hours, I searched all over the internet, but I still don't understand why it doesn't work.

I just run `npx tsc` but I get this error:

```sh
$ npx tsc
src/index.ts:2:24 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'React'.

2 import * as React from 'React';
                         ~~~~~~~


Found 1 error.
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "es2016",
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "dist/types",
    "outDir": "dist/lib",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "jsx": "react",
    "noResolve": false,
    "allowJs": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "playground"
  ]
}
```

src/index.ts:

```js
import lodash from 'lodash';
import * as React from 'React';
```

packages.json:

```
{
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.144",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.7",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.11",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.4.1",
    "typescript": "^3.6.4"
  }
}
```

What gives?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably install `react` as a dependency and not a `devDependency`.
Also, make the react import the first line in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from installing react as a dependency by running,

```
npm i react
```

you might want to import the default exported module instead.

```
import React from 'react';
```

And on your `tsconfig.json`, you can set `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` as `true`.

```
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
```

In addition, you may read more about integrating [TypeScript with React](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/).